# Custom Placeholder Component React-Select

Tags: react-select

How can I set a custom placeholder element?

I'd like to add a search icon when the field is empty

Thanks.

Comment: Have you ever tried it? In that case share the code that you've done and then we can help you.

Comment: @dlopez since the documentation doesn't indicate it I didn't event try. Thanks for nudging me on that one.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

TLDR; I just figured out that I can just simply pass a component

I guess I did not get that a node could be a component.

The documentation indicates:

```
placeholder: PropTypes.string || PropTypes.node
```

```js
type placeholder = string | React.ReactNode
```

The following line comes from the source. As you see, it allows a component to be passed.

```js
return !this.state.inputValue ? <div className="Select-placeholder">{this.props.placeholder}</div> : null;
```

So I can use

```js
<Select placeholder={<div>Type to search</div>} />
```

Comment: can u pls eloborate with using search bar icon in the placeholder , how to use font-awesome icon in the placeholder, help me out

Answer (score 7):

```js
<Select placeholder={<div>Type to search</div>} />
```

works

Comment: it's actually `<Select placeholder="Type to search"/>`